# Ошибка с кириллицей в скрипте Powershell utf-8

Tags: utf-8, powershell, кириллица

Я написал небольшой скрипт powershell и сохранил файл в кодировке utf-8. Пытаюсь задать переменной текст на кириллице:

```
$text="<pre> --- Новая задача ---</pre>`n`n<b>Ключ: Тема</b>`nАвтор: Григорян"
```

При запуске скрипта получаю следующую ошибку:

```
At C:\tools\test.ps1:1 char:110
+ ... "Ñ?D,D3D_Ñ?Ñ?D½"
+                    ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\tools\telegram_test.ps1:1 char:96
+ ... nD?D²Ñ,D_Ñ?: D"Ñ?D,D3D_Ñ?Ñ?D½"
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Ñ?D,D3D_Ñ?Ñ?D½"
$text
' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseExcepti
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Насколько я понимаю, происходит преобразование текста, в нем появляются спец. символы и происходит ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это обойти? Кодировка файла должна быть именно utf-8.

**[UPD]** Пока что единственный вариант, который я смог найти – создание .txt-файла в кодировке UTF-8 и считывание переменной $text из него.

Comment: UTF-8 -> UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: В такой случае я вижу '??????' вместо текста на кириллице :)

Comment: Где именно Вы это видите?

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать файл в непростой кодировке "UTF-8", а "UTF-8 со спецификацией". Можно пересохранить через блокнот. Тогда код с русскими символами в PowerShell в файле ps1 исполнится

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема была при записи PowerShell скрипта в кодировке UTF-8, использовал CP1251 и это решило проблему с русскими символами в значениях переменных.
Пример кода Java:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("script.ps1"), "CP1251"));
out.write(data);
out.close();
```